# Using plotly to draw boxplot for two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, boxplot

I am trying to use plotly to draw boxplots for two groups, it works fine if I do not implement with shiny app, and the figure looks like this:
[image]

But when I want to implement this figure in Shiny app, two groups are correlates together and now looks like:
[image]

My codes are written as:

```
g2 <- ggplot(df_CL, aes(x = factor(Population, levels = c('NP', 'T2', 'T3', 'PP')), y= value, fill = interaction(Population, variable) )) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')+
  xlab('Population') +
  ylab('Clearnce (L/hr)') +
  labs(fill = 'Legend') + 
  theme_grey()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D","#C77CFF","#7CAE00","#00BFC4","#faa49e","#ddafff","#a0e100","#00f1f7"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size =16))
  p2 <- ggplotly(g2) # Convert to a plotly object.
```

What's the problem with my codes?

Comment: Why do you have both `stat_boxplot` and `geom_boxplot`? You could try specifically passing in the position, e.g. `geom_boxplot(position = position_doge(width = 0.4))`.

Comment: I tried to add %>%layout(boxmode = "group") and now it worked, but the shape becomes much smaller...I don't know how to fix this

Comment: You can try to add some data (with `dput()`, or some fake) to improve the chances to get an answer, making your code reproducible.